# HTML mailto form not breaking lines for submission every time

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, email

I have an html form that uses the mailto element and when I send it, it will sometimes just clump all the text together without any spaces.  If I close the document and reopen it, it will then create the line breaks, like its supposed to.

```
 <form action="mailto:akinettieweininger@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<h1> Sign-up Today! </h1>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  <b> Child #1 Full Name: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Child#1_name"> <br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Child #1 Date of Birth <br>
  <input type="date" name="Child#1_dob"> <br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Child #2 Full Name: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Child#2_name"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Child #2 Date of Birth: <br>
  <input type="date" name="Child#2_dob"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Parent/Guardian #1: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Parent#1_name"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Parent/Guardian #1 Phone Number: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Parent#1_phone"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Parent/Guardian #2: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Parent#2_name"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Parent/Guardian #2 Phone Number: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Parent#2_phone"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Home Address: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Home_Address"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  Primary Contact Email: <br>
  <input type="text" name="Contact_Email"><br>
</div>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  <br> SELECT WEEKS YOUR CHILDREN WILL BE ATTENDING: </b> <br>
</div> <input type="checkbox" name="Week#1" value="Selected"> Week #1 June 29th – July 2nd<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Week#2" value="Selected"> Week #2 July 6th – July 9th<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Week#3" value="Selected"> Week #3 July 13th – July 16th <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Week#4" value="Selected"> Week #4 July 20th – July 23rd <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Week#5" value="Selected"> Week #5 July 27th – July 30th <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="Week#6" value="Selected"> Week #6 August 3rd – August 6th<br>
<div class="Individual-boxes">
  <br> <b> Do you want to apply for a discount? </b> <br>
</div> <input type="radio" name="Discount" value="Discount_sibling"> Sibling<br>
<input type="radio" name="Discount" value="Discount"> Returning Student <br>
<input type="radio" name="Discount_returning" value="Discount_Bundle"> 6 Week Bundle<br>
<br>
<b>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Select Payment Option:
</b> <br> </div>
<input type="radio" name="Pay_method" value="Paypal"> Paypal<br>
<input type="radio" name="Pay_method" value="Cash"> Cash<br>
<input type="radio" name="Pay_method" value="Venmo"> Venmo<br>
<br>
<b>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> I would like to pay: </div>
</b> <br>
<input type="radio" name="Pay_amount" value="Balance_in_full"> Balance in full<br>
<input type="radio" name="Pay_amount" value="Deposit_pay_by_5/31/20"> Deposit now & payment in full by 5/31/20 <br>
<input type="radio" name="Pay_amount" value="Payment_plan_contract"> Deposit now & apply for payment plan contract
<br>
<br>
<b>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> List the names & phone numbers of 3 people, other than parents/guardians who are
    allowed to pick up your child: <br> <br> </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> First contact: <br> <input type="text" name="Contact#1"><br>

  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> First contacts phone number: <br> <input type="text" name="Contact#1_phone"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Second contact: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Contact#2"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Second contacts phone number: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Contact#2_phone"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Third contact: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Contact#3"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Third contacts phone number: <br>
    <input type="text" name="Contact#3_phone"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Please list any allergies to foods, medications, etc... <br>
    <input type="text" name="Allergies"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> How did you hear about us? <br>
    <input type="text" name="Heard_from"><br> <br> <br>
  </div>
  <div class="Individual-boxes"> Do you give permission to have your child’s photograph or video be taken for use by
    MFASP in program brochures, annual
    reports, websites, social media sites, and other promotional materials and for release to local newspapers?
</b> <br> <br> </div>
<input type="radio" name="Permission_photography" value="Yes"> Yes <br>
<input type="radio" name="Permission_photography" value="No"> No <br>
<div class="middle">
  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</div>
```

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/daniel-albano/pen/mdJbqPP?editors=1000

Comment: What is your question? What you expected looking for?

Comment: When I send an email directed by the form, I want the text to be organized by breaks